# Differentiate Array base on Value And Sum Of Array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have array and first of all I want to differentiate base on site(key) and site is not limited to 1 or 2
And then sum of opening balance and closing balance of site 
like all site(888) total_balance = opening_balance + closing_balance
(999) total_balance = opening_balance + closing_balance

```
"games": [
    {
        "id": 240,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "888",
        "opening_balance": 5,
        "closing_balance": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 243,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "999",
        "opening_balance": 3,
        "closing_balance": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 244,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "888",
        "opening_balance": 5,
        "closing_balance": 6
    },
```

And want output like
 (site => 888, total_balance => 22 , site => 999, total_balance => 7
(it could b string))

And code I tried:

```
{
    $collection = collect(Site::all())->map(function($item , $key){
                            return $item["name"];
                        });

    $record = Game::whereIn('site',$collection)->get();
    dd($record);

    /*$bySite = array();
        foreach ($record as $key => $item) {
            if(!isset($bySite[$item['site']])) {
                $bySite[$item['site']] = array();
            }
            $bySite[$item['site']][$key] = $item;
        }*/
}
```

after this code which I commented output is
but then I don't know how sum of this

```
{
"888": {
    "0": {
        "id": 240,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "888",
        "opening_balance": 5,
        "closing_balance": 6
    },
   "2": {
        "id": 244,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "888",
        "opening_balance": 5,
        "closing_balance": 6
    },
  },
"999": {
    "1": {
        "id": 243,
        "user_id": 1,
        "site": "999",
        "opening_balance": 3,
        "closing_balance": 4,
```

Comment: You need to  include `total_balance` in all items Or you need to group by `site`  and include the `total_balance` ? Can you be more specific with the output you want ?

Comment: yes sir group by site and then include total balance

Comment: Can you specify the output you are expecting? Please edit & specify your output structure.

Comment: required = site => 888, total_balance => 22
site => 999, total_balance => 7
It could be string i havnt problem just i need this output.... i need all total balance of site 888 seperate and 999 sepearte  and so on (111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Laravel Collection.

```
$games =  [
    [
        "id" =>  240,
        "user_id" =>  1,
        "site" =>  "888",
        "opening_balance" =>  5,
        "closing_balance" =>  6
    ],
    [
        "id" =>  243,
        "user_id" =>  1,
        "site" =>  "999",
        "opening_balance" =>  3,
        "closing_balance" =>  4
    ],
    [
        "id" =>  244,
        "user_id" =>  1,
        "site" =>  "888",
        "opening_balance" =>  5,
        "closing_balance" =>  6
    ]
];

$games = collect($games);

$games = $games->groupBy('site')->map(function($game, $key){
    return [
        'site' => $key,
        'total_balance' => $game->sum('opening_balance') + $game->sum('closing_balance'),
    ];
})->values();

dd($games->toArray());
```

And the output would be,

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
        "site" => 888
        "total_balance" => 22
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
        "site" => 999
        "total_balance" => 7
    ]
]
```

Code Snippet : https://implode.io/5aPGeH

Comment: Thanku So much sir Your answer is really valuable ... but i did it with another way in the morning.

Comment: You are welcome. If this resolved your issue, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

step
1. foreach ($collection)
2. sum the value and store in array like ($collection->sum('opening_balance'), ($collection->sum('closing_balance')
3. then sum the variable
4. stop loop
5. then $final = $final['site'] . "  =>  " . $final['sum'];